# Infinite loop that shouldn't happen

Tags: javascript

**Please ask me if you need any more information about the project, or an working example!**

Hello everyone,
I have been working on a project lately which I made for learning Javascript.
It is a calculator but one thing doesn't seem to work. I am trying to add a power function for example 6<sup>2</sup> = 36. The calculator work but I have a problem with the syntax of javascript calculation.
Let me give you an example:
If I click 6 and then the <sup>2</sup> button it needs add to the calculation

```
Math.pow(6, 2)
```

I already started a piece of code but it keeps getting stuck in a loop and I have no idea how to fix this.

```
function EnterPower2()
{
    var InputValue = document.getElementById("CalcBar").innerHTML;
    var TrueInputValue = document.getElementById("TrueCalcBar").value;
    var stringLength = TrueInputValue.length;
    var lastChar = TrueInputValue.charAt(stringLength - 1);
    var AmountOfNumbers = 1;
    if(lastChar != "*" || lastChar != "+" || lastChar != "-" || lastChar != "/" || lastChar != null)
    {
        RepeatBundle();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("CalcBar").innerHTML = InputValue + "^2";
        document.getElementById("TrueCalcBar").value = TrueInputValue + "Math.pow(" + lastCharCalculated + ", 2)";
    }
    function RepeatBundle()
    {
        AmountOfNumbers + parseFloat(1);
        var AnotherlastChar = TrueInputValue.charAt(stringLength -AmountOfNumbers);
        TrueInputValue = TrueInputValue.slice(0, -AmountOfNumbers);
        var lastCharCalculated = lastChar + AnotherlastChar;
        if(AnotherlastChar != "*" || AnotherlastChar != "+" || AnotherlastChar != "-" || AnotherlastChar != "/" || AnotherlastChar != '')
            {
                RepeatBundle();
            }
    }   
}
```

What I want to happen is
if I enter for example 66 it executes the JS and it sees that there are two numbers and the last character is NOT a plus or empty it loops it until it sees an end so it does Math.pow(66, 2)

This code keeps looping and looping and I dont know how to fix this, please help me! Thanks

Comment: You variable *AmountOfNumbers* should be declared as global => outside EnterPower2. And function *Repeatbundle* too.

Comment: The line `AmountOfNumbers + parseFloat(1);` probably does not do what you think it does.

Comment: What does that mean (Sorry) @ADreNaLiNe-DJ

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ There isnt much that the HTML code can help with.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is the cause of the infinite repeat.

On this line:

```
if(AnotherlastChar != "*" || AnotherlastChar != "+" || AnotherlastChar != "-" || AnotherlastChar != "/" || AnotherlastChar != '')
```

You are basically saying any character should cause it to repeat. If it is a `*`, the second condition will be true and it will repeat. If it is a `+`, the first condition will be true and it will repeat.

You need to re-evaluate your conditions. `||` is the OR operator, so if any one of those conditions matches, the code inside the `if` will be run. You probably want some `&&` (AND) conditions instead.

If you only want it to repeat when it's not a `*` entered, change it to:

```
if(AnotherlastChar != "*")
```

If you want it to repeat when it's not any of the maths operators entered that you've listed, use `&&`s like this:

```
if(AnotherlastChar != "*" && AnotherlastChar != "+" && AnotherlastChar != "-" && AnotherlastChar != "/" && AnotherlastChar != '')
```

Comment: No because it needs to check IF the last character is NOT a * then repeat the process

Comment: And if it is a `*`, it checks if it NOT a `+` next - since a `*` is not a `+`, it repeats again

Comment: So what do I need to change then?

Comment: You need to think about what exact conditions you want to repeat for, and only include them in the `if` - if you want it to only repeat if it's not a `*`, take away everything after `AnotherlastChar != "*"`. Edit - I've updated my answer with 2 possible scenarios

Comment: This worked but now it removes everything from the calculation and it doesnt see a plus or anything and it says undenefied..

Comment: Probably to do with the fact you are re-defining `lastCharCalculated` every time the function repeats. You need to define that outside the function and then just set the value without `var` inside it

Answer (score -1):

Used The RepeatBundle() out the main function....
recurcivaly called that functnion

```
function EnterPower2()
{
    var InputValue = document.getElementById("CalcBar").innerHTML;
    var TrueInputValue = document.getElementById("TrueCalcBar").value;
    var stringLength = TrueInputValue.length;
    var lastChar = TrueInputValue.charAt(stringLength - 1);
    var AmountOfNumbers = 1;
    if(lastChar != "*" || lastChar != "+" || lastChar != "-" || lastChar != "/" || lastChar != null)
    {
        RepeatBundle();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("CalcBar").innerHTML = InputValue + "^2";
        document.getElementById("TrueCalcBar").value = TrueInputValue + "Math.pow(" + lastCharCalculated + ", 2)";
    }

} function RepeatBundle()
    {
        AmountOfNumbers + parseFloat(1);
        var AnotherlastChar = TrueInputValue.charAt(stringLength -AmountOfNumbers);
        TrueInputValue = TrueInputValue.slice(0, -AmountOfNumbers);
        var lastCharCalculated = lastChar + AnotherlastChar;
        if(AnotherlastChar != "*" || AnotherlastChar != "+" || AnotherlastChar != "-" || AnotherlastChar != "/" || AnotherlastChar != '')
            {
                RepeatBundle();
            }
    }
```